# Adding an image in place of product in listing page

Tags: magento

I am looking to add one image in place of a product on a category listing page - one image occupying all the space which would normally be taken up by the product image, name, price etc. on the listing page.  I am able to add a static block no problem, but can't quite figure this out.  Is this possible with Magento's native functionality?

Comment: What you have tried ? post your code then you can expect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just using css property background-image. if you want to add image in whole content in listing page then it parent div use background-image, if you want to give image in each product block in listing page then also use css.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the phtml template and in the loop where the products are being shown, check for the id/sku of the product, for which you want to put a custom image. Then simply echo your custom image and continue with the loop.

Pseudo Code:

```
foreach (products as product)
{

   if(product->sku == 'YOUR_PRODUCT')
   {
      echo CUSTOM_IMAGE;
      continue;
    }
//LEAVE THE OTHER PARTS OF TEMPLATE AS IT IS
echo product->name;
echo product->image; // and others
}
```